# compilation error in macro

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I have downloaded jsvm software, and I am getting many errors while compiling. Few of them is as follows.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/algorithmfwd.h:248:41: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
```

And the file algorithmfwd.h is as follows

```
 template<typename _Tp>
const _Tp&
min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&);
template<typename _Tp, typename _Compare>
const _Tp&
min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare);
```

// min_element

Comment: Your error is for 'max', your code shows 'min'...

Comment: Your error if for 'macro', your code shows 'template'.

Comment: Actually, the error is for a macro expansion. That happens before templates are even parsed (preprocessor step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere, you have defined a macro `max`, which is not allowed if you
include any headers from the standard library (which has a set of
overloaded functions named `max`).  You'll have to find out where this
macro is defined, and get rid of it.  Two immediate possibilities come
to mind:

- You've defined it as a macro in one of your headers.  Get rid of it.
- Microsoft defines (or defined—I've not check VC10) both `min` and
  `max` as macros in one of its headers.  Add `/DNOMINMAX` to
  your compiler options to suppress this.
- Some other library you can't control has defined it.  Wrap this
  libraries headers in private headers, which include the library header,
  then do:

  ```
      #undef min
      #undef max
  ```

  Use these wrappers instead of the library headers you were given (and
  pressure the library provider to correct this).

Comment: I just want to point that a similar error could happen if you define a macro ``compare``. In this case, you would get the error ``"compare" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2``.

Answer (score 3):

The error is quite explicit:

> /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/algorithmfwd.h:248:41: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2

Before inclusion of that particular header, you have defined a *macro* `max` that takes 3 arguments. Macros are *evil* in that they are applied everywhere that the identifier appears. Review where in the code you are defining that macro and remove it, or at the very least change it into upper case (common convention for macros) so that it does not get expanded in all other headers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as, in addition to the functions in `algorithmfwd.h` have a preprocessor-style macro also named `max`. Try to find whoever is defining this and avoid include that header files, or use `#undef max` if all else fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the max macro. Anyway seems that you are trying to use a macro with one more parameter than what it is expecting.

> I am getting many errors while compiling

Try to solve your errors in order, because one mistake can influence the next.