# GObject Compilation Error in Macro Expansion While Defining Class

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor, gobject

## Problem

Using GObject and C, I am trying to create a subclass of the class GObject named "Bar" in module "Foo". However, the macro "G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE" (defined in gobject/gtype.h) expands incorrectly. Instead of expanding into FOO_BAR, it expands into nothing. So instead of expanding into:

```
... FooBar * FOO_BAR (gpointer ptr) { ...
```

It instead expands into:

```
... FooBar * (gpointer ptr) { ...
```

## Error Message

I expect it to compile but instead gcc gives a syntax error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from foo-bar.h:4,
                 from foo-bar.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:1407:77: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ptr’
 1407 | USED static inline ModuleObjName * MODULE##_##OBJ_NAME (gpointer ptr) {                       \
      |                                                                  ^~~

 foo-bar.h:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE’
   10 | G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (FooBar, foo_bar, FOO, BAR, GObject)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

## Definition of Macro

This definition comes from the glib 2.66.7 library. I did not define it myself. I include it for the sake of completeness.

```
#define G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE(ModuleObjName, module_obj_name, MODULE, OBJ_NAME, ParentName)  \
  GType module_obj_name##_get_type (void);                                                  \
  G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS                                                          \
  typedef struct _##ModuleObjName ModuleObjName;                                            \ 
  typedef struct { ParentName##Class parent_class; } ModuleObjName##Class;                  \
                                                                                            \
  _GLIB_DEFINE_AUTOPTR_CHAINUP (ModuleObjName, ParentName)                                  \
  G_DEFINE_AUTOPTR_CLEANUP_FUNC (ModuleObjName##Class, g_type_class_unref)                  \
                                                                                            \
  G_GNUC_UNUSED static inline ModuleObjName * MODULE##_##OBJ_NAME (gpointer ptr) {          \
    return G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST (ptr, module_obj_name##_get_type (), ModuleObjName); }\
  G_GNUC_UNUSED static inline gboolean MODULE##_IS_##OBJ_NAME (gpointer ptr) {              \
    return G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE (ptr, module_obj_name##_get_type ()); }               \
  G_GNUC_END_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS
```

## Partial Pre-Processor Output

I included the definition that contains the syntax error and formatted it for readability:

```
__attribute__((__unused__)) static inline FooBar * (gpointer ptr) {
  return (((FooBar*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) (ptr), (foo_bar_get_type ()))));
}
```

What's odd is that the definition following does get pre-processed correctly:

```
__attribute__((__unused__)) static inline gboolean FOO_IS_BAR (gpointer ptr) {
  return ((__extension__ ({
    GTypeInstance *__inst = (GTypeInstance*) (ptr);
    GType __t = (foo_bar_get_type ());
    gboolean __r;
    if (!__inst) __r = (0);
    else if (__inst->g_class && __inst->g_class->g_type == __t) __r = (!(0));
    else __r = g_type_check_instance_is_a (__inst, __t); __r; }))); 
}
```

## Full Minimal Example

I have included a minimal example that causes my error below.

foo-bar.h

```
#ifndef FOO_BAR
#define FOO_BAR

#include <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define FOO_TYPE_BAR (foo_bar_get_type ())

G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (FooBar, foo_bar, FOO, BAR, GObject)

G_END_DECLS

#endif /* FOO_BAR */
```

foo-bar.c

```
#include "foo-bar.h"

struct _FooBar
{
    GObject parent_instance;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (FooBar, foo_bar, G_TYPE_OBJECT);

static void foo_bar_class_init (FooBarClass *klass)
{

}

static void foo_bar_init (FooBar *app)
{

}
```

makefile

```
foo-bar.o: foo-bar.c
    gcc -c foo-bar.c $(shell pkg-config --cflags gobject-2.0) -o foo-bar.o
# included to debug the macro
foo-bar.pp: foo-bar.c
    gcc -E foo-bar.c $(shell pkg-config --cflags gobject-2.0) -o foo-bar.pp
```

## Versions

- glib 2.66.7
- gcc 10.2.1
- Linux (Fedora 33)

## What I have tried

I have studied [glib's documentation on how to create a new class](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html) and as far as I can tell I am doing it correctly. I have also looked up how token pasting and macro expansion work, and also tried googling my error. It must be something obvious, but I cannot figure out what. I also tried declaring a derivable class with private data, but while finding a minimal example I changed it to a final class without private data and still have the same error. I read about the ## operator [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) and still cannot tell what is going wrong.

## Related Stack Overflow Questions

Finally, I have looked at the following related stackoverflow posts:

My error is that concatenated tokens are not being emitted by the pre-processor. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477759/error-in-macro-expansion) post the user defines their own macro and asks why one invocation works and the other doesn't. I am using a library and not my own macro.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676793/syntax-error-in-macro-expansion) question is asking about why a macro expands differently in unicode mode versus ascii mode. I am not dealing with unicode so it is not relevant.

I am not using C++, only C which does not have syntax for generics, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559265/behaviour-of-define-macro-expansion-in-c) question does not apply to me.

Since I am not using XCode [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741820/macro-expansion-producing-defined-has-undefined-behavior) question does not solve my problem.

I understand how macro expansion is supposed to work, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448086/macro-expansion) question does tell me anything I don't already know.

I am not defining any new macros and do not have and problems with namespace collision, unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934145/compilation-error-in-macro) question.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672618/macro-expansion-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662880/unfamiilar-macro-expansion) question the user is not aware of the concatenation operator in macros. I am, and my problem is that it does not work the way I expect it too. So saying the operator exists does not help me.

[This question is close to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547085/stopping-macro-expansion), but it is occuring because an argument to a macro was not provided. I am providing all arguments so it does not help me.

[This question the user is using the pasting operator when they don't need to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924263/macro-name-expansion-syntax). In my case the pasting operator is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was something dumb. Posting this in case anyone runs across this answer.

The problem is my include guard. It should be FOO_BAR_H since the name of the file is foo-bar.h. However, it is defined as FOO_BAR. When gobject generates the token "FOO_BAR" the pre-processor realizes that it is a macro that has already been defined, but in this case the definition is empty. Nevertheless, it replaces the macro with its definition.

The solution is just replacing "FOO_BAR" with "FOO_BAR_H" in the include guard.